# Set correct path for BibTeX via Rubber

Tags: bibtex, compiling, makefile, rubber

## Setup

I am using *Rubber* to compile my *LaTeX* document.
In my root folder I have `main.tex`, `mybib.bib` (both coming from [here](http://www.bibtex.org/Using/)) and `Makefile`.

## `main.tex`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\title{My Article}
\author{Nobody Jr.}
\date{Today}
\maketitle

Blablabla said Nobody ~\cite{Nobody06}.

\bibliography{mybib}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

## `mybib.bib`

```
@misc{ Nobody06,
       author = "Nobody Jr",
       title = "My Article",
       year = "2006" }
```

## `Makefile`

```
.PHONY: clean

LATEX_SRC=$(wildcard *.tex)
REFS=$(wildcard *.bib)

all: main.pdf

%.pdf: %.tex $(LATEX_SRC) $(REFS)
    mkdir -p build
    rubber --into build --short --pdf $<
    rubber-info --into build --check $<

clean:
    rm -rf build
```

Running `make` will complain that

```
running: bibtex main.aux...
[biblio] There were errors running bibtex.
build/main.aux:3: [bibtex] I couldn't open database file mybib.bib
```

## Workaround

Replacing `\bibliography{mybib}{}` with `\bibliography{../mybib}{}` in `main.tex` is a valid workaround.

## Question

Now, how do I get *Rubber* to tell *BibTeX* the correct folder? Both `main.tex` and `myref.bib` are arguments to `rubber`, so I'm not sure how *BibTeX* is not seeing the latter.
My `main.aux` contains the line `\bibdata{mybib}`, which is causing the problem, and that's why adding the `../` to `main.tex` was giving a working solution, but I rather have a better understanding about how to use *Rubber* than patching its behaviour myself, since I believe I might be misusing it.

Comment: I don't use `rubber` but I doubt this is really `rubber`'s problem. BibTeX is run on the generated `.aux` file and so looks for `mybib.bib` from the location of that `.aux`. Usually, you'd put your `.bib` file into your personal TEXMF tree rather than the working directory, which isn't very convenient for general usage, so this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I don't use rubber but the problem is your build directory: you are calling bibtex there and the aux is telling bibtex, that the bib is in the current directory. You can either call bibtex from the location of the bib with `bibtex build/main.aux`, or copy all files (including the tex and the bib) to the build directory before the compilation (imho the better way, compilations steps are easier to handle in the long run if everything is in the same folder).

Comment: @cfr: I was not aware one usually puts the bibliography in any special directory. Nevertheless, this is not an option, if your documents lives in a repository and it's expected to be self contained.
@UlrikeFischer: as I said, I'm not running `bibtex`, `rubber` is. That's why I posted this question, i.e. how do I get `rubber` to call `bibtex` from the root directory? I'm not looking for "fixes", since I've already found one. I'm trying to understand why others don't have a similar issue, and what's their workflow and setup. Btw, thank you both for commenting.

Comment: It seems to me that @UlrikeFischer and I have already suggested several ways in which others might not have this problem i.e. we've described common workflows and configurations which would work.

Comment: @cfr: Yes, I am thankful you both did. As I said, I was not aware of the *personal TEXMF tree*. And I know that removing the `--into build` option (*i.e.* having all files in the same directory) actually does not throw this issue. I wrote this question to understand whether I am misusing `rubber`, which is very likely, since I'm a newbie. I did not intend to sound arrogant; my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this line to the main LaTeX file does solve the issue.

```
% rubber: bibtex.path ../
```

Now BibTeX will know about the file structure of the project.